# Not able to upload a file programatically in Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, sharepoint-addin

I am getting following exception while trying to add a file :

> SPException: It may refer to a nonexistent file or folder, or refer to
>   a valid file or folder that is not in the current Web.

**Code for uploading :**

```
spFile = spWeb.Files.Add(
                        docUrl,
                        uploadStream,
                        true, // overwrite or add a new version
                        uploadMessage.Metadata.CheckInComment ?? "", //check-in comment to use when creating the file in the collection. (can't be NULL)
                        false); // don't check the required fields when saving the file
```

The issue does not occur while manually uploading the file from the browser but while adding the file in a Document Library from the code using SPWeb.Files.Add the above mentioned exception occurs.
Please note that the Content DB of the web application is not full.

Comment: Could you share the code snippet.

Comment: I've added code snippet

Comment: How you have initialized spWeb? I mean what is the context? Root/Site? Could you please share the snippet of initialization?